# Java configure buildpath to navigate project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to navigate in my project using the `Ctrl + Alt + H` keys (open call hirearchy) in Eclipse Neon IDE and STS ide.
I can not keep sailing in the lower levels , as I only see the method members

[image]

I saw in some articles mentioned that this problem could be caused in buildpath

Any suggestion

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: thanks for your comment i added to my question ...Eclipse Neon IDE and STS ide

Comment: Is `testRetrieveInformation()` really called by another method?? Do you expect more methods under that node ??

Comment: yes ,  other members can keep navigating